# Using CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) inside Asp.Net WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, chromium-embedded

I've packed Joel solution (http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2013/12/headless-chromium-in-c-with-cefglue/) in a library because I need to use it inside an ASP.Net  WebApplication. The library works fine as standalone but hangs on (on some internal unidentified process) when invoked inside a webapp. Have you ever tryed this running mode? Have you got an idea about what could be the problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you figure out how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you running the ASP.NET site and under what security profile? My guess is that this is going wrong because it is running in a context where GDI operations aren't allowed. Even if no window is created, GDI is still used to do the rendering.

This same problem has affected me with PhantomJS which is why I ask.

Comment: Using GDI+ "from ASP.NET" shouldn't be a problem, since GDI+ is still used internally by, for example, `System.Drawing`, which is popular for web related image manipulation. Full Trust will likely be needed.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I asked where it was hosted and what security profile was it running under. Azure, for example, disables GDI as far as I can tell.

Comment: Aha, didn't know that. Either way, questions to the OP are usually best posted as comments on the OP's question, not as answers.